# Cannot query table from datalab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I have a dataset with tables set up within Big Query which I can query just fine using the BQ UI, however I am getting an error when attempting to run a standard query from datalab.

I can get the table schema returned when I run

```
%%bq tables describe --name "my-project.my_dataset.my_table"
```

and also I can get access to the meta data

```
table1=bq.Table("my-project.my_dataset.my_table")
table1.metadata.rows

Result: 637043
```

However when I run

```
%%bq query --name testQuery 
SELECT * FROM `my-project.my_dataset.my_table`
```

I receive the error

```
RequestException: HTTP request failed: Not found: Job my-project:job__SSPF9nCudKqIFZT8N4yvp_SUDb5
```

I have tried using the various different ways of sending the same query as well as sampling but no joy.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and found the solution here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter

Try to install this library:

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]
```

Call the magic notebook command:

```
%load_ext google.cloud.bigquery
```

And then run the query this way:

```
%%bigquery
SELECT
    source_year AS year,
    COUNT(is_male) AS birth_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year DESC
LIMIT 15
```